# Python - Adding SEM to px.box (plotly express box plot)

Tags: python, graph, statistics, plotly

this is my graph:
[image]

This is how I created it:

```
fig = px.box(data_comb, 
             x='task_level', 
             y='value',   
             color='task_level', 
             title = title+"<br><sup>"+stitle+"</sup>",)
fig.update_traces(boxpoints=False) 
fig.show()
```

I want to add SEM (standard error of means) lines instead of the automatic whisker lines that represent min and max values.

Any idea how can I do it? is it possible to do it with plotly express?

I tried looking online but couldn't find anything...

Comment: Have you looked here https://plotly.com/python/error-bars/ ?